# Get returned data from Jquery Returned Object for each object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did give this a read but it didn't quite help me.

[How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

I am trying to get the values of the response

```
response(data.suggestions);
```

The below is what I get if I console.log(data.suggestions);

```
(1) [{…}, {…}]
0:
id: "10"
name: "Iron Man"
1:
id: "93"
name: "Purple Dinosaur Inc."
```

How can I get the values by the keys.

so something like

```
response(data.suggestions["name"]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the values of the specific names you can iterate over the array and read the name property of the current object.

```
obje.forEach(x => console.log(x.name))
```

To store the values in a new array I would recommend using `map()`

```
const valArr = obje.map(x => x.name);
```

```js
const obje = [{
    id: "10",
    name: "Iron Man"

  },
  {
    id: "93",
    name: "Purple Dinosaur Inc."

  }
]

obje.forEach(x => console.log(x.name));
const valArr = obje.map(x => x.name);

console.log(valArr)
```

Comment: I like this, it's much cleaner than a simple for-loop but somewhat complicated for beginners.

Comment: @Haring10 Agree, but using functional programming in JS has a lot of benefits, writting less code produces less potential misstakes and is easier to read (When you are used to it).

Answer (score 2):

This is an array but you are trying to access it as an object.

You need to access the index first.

Use the following:

```
console.log(data.suggestions[0]["name"]);
```

That should give you "Iron Man" in this case.

If you want to cycle through them, you can use a for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.suggestions.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.suggestions[i]["name"]);
}
```

This will print out each "name" key from all of your objects in the console.

Comment: And how can I go through each of the objects?

Comment: So I need to return every objects Name

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was super helpful. Much appreciated <3